# Errores de compilación en lenguaje C

Tags: c

```
ej.c:75:9: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
   75 |         addr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
      |         ^~~~
ej.c:75:9: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘addr’ [-Wimplicit-int]
ej.c:75:22: error: ‘shmid’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   75 |         addr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
      |                      ^~~~~
ej.c:77:9: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘switch’
   77 |         switch ( fork() ) {
      |         ^~~~~~
ej.c:173:9: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘return’
  173 |         return 0;
      |         ^~~~~~
ej.c:174:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
  174 | }
      | ^
```

Estos son los errores que me aparecen al compilar el siguiente código, por favor, ayuda.

Necesito crear una aplicación formada por dos procesos dependientes, mediante una relación padre-hijo.

> El proceso padre obtendrá por parámetro el nombre de un directorio. A partir de dicho nombre, el proceso padre determinará si es un directorio o no.
>
> Si no existe ningún directorio con ese nombre, el proceso padre debe mostrar en pantalla un mensaje. Si existe el directorio, el proceso padre obtendrá el nombre de cada archivo y subdirectorio contenido en dicho directorio.
>
> Para cada nombre obtenido, el proceso padre lo enviará al proceso hijo para que este lo visualice por pantalla. Una vez visualizada toda la información del directorio, ambos procesos terminarán su ejecución.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define KEY 100
#define EL 0
#define ED 1
#define MB 2
#define N 256

int main (argc, argv)
    int argc;
    char **argv; {
    
    int status;
    int semid;
    int shmid;
    
    int IN, OUT;
    
    struct sembuf sem_oper;
    
    union semun {
        int val;
        struct semid_ds *semstat;
        unsigned short *array;
    } arg;
    
    struct buffer {
        char nombre[N];
    } buffer, *addr;
    
    DIR *dir;
    
    struct dirent *ent;
    
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("\n ERROR, no se ha introducido ningún parámetro\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("\n ERROR, hay parámetros de más\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    semid = semget(KEY, 3, 0770 | IPC_CREAT);
    
    if (semid == -1) {
    printf("\n ERROR en la creación de semáforos\n\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    
    arg.array = (unsigned short *) malloc (sizeof (short)*3);
    arg.array[EL] = N;
    arg.array[ED] = 0;
    arg.array[MB] = 1;
    
    semctl (semid, 3, SETALL, arg);
    
    shmid = shmget(KEY, sizeof(buffer)*N, 0770 | IPC_CREAT);
    
    if (shmid == -1)
    printf("\n ERROR en la creación de Memoria Compartidan\n\n");
    exit(1);        //no 2?
    }
    
    addr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    
    switch ( fork() ) {
    case -1:
        printf("\n ERROR, no se ha podido crear el proceso hijo \n");
        exit(3);
        break;
    case 0:
        dir = opendir(argv[1]);
        
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            sem_oper.sem_num = ED;
            sem_oper.sem_op = -1;
            sem_oper.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
            
            semop (semid, &sem_oper, 1);
            
            sem_oper.sem_num = MB;
            sem_oper.sem_op = -1;
            sem_oper.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
            
            semop (semid, &sem_oper, 1);
            
                buffer = addr[OUT];
                OUT = (OUT +1) % N;
                
            sem_oper.sem_num = MB;
            sem_oper.sem_op = -1;
            sem_oper.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
            
            semop (semid, &sem_oper, 1);
            
            sem_oper.sem_num = EL;
            sem_oper.sem_op = 1;
            sem_oper.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
            
            semop (semid, &sem_oper, 1);
            
                printf("\n Nombre del archivo: &s\n", buffer.nombre);
        }
        
        printf("\n");   //se puede quitar digo yo
        exit(0);
        break;
        
    default:
        
        dir = opendir(argv[1]);
        
        if(dir == NULL) {
            printf("\n directorio no existente\n\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        while ((ent = readdir(dir) != NULL) {
            strcpy(buffer.nombre, ent->d_name);
            
            sem_oper.sem_num = EL;
            sem_oper.sem:num = -1;
            sem_oper.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
            
            semop(semid, &sem_oper, 1)
            
            sem_oper.sem_num = MB;
            sem_oper.sem_op = -1;
            sem_oper.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
            
            semop(semid, &sem_oper, 1);
            
                addr[N] = buffer;
                IN = (IN +1) % N;
            
            sem_oper.sem_num = MB;
            sem_oper.sem_op = 1;
            sem_oper.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
            
            semop(semid, &sem_oper, 1);
            
            sem_oper.sem_num = ED;
            sem_oper.sem_op = 1;
            sem_oper.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
            
            semop(semid, &sem_oper, 1);
        }
        close(dir);
        
        wait(&status);
        
        semctl(semid, 3, IPC_RMID, 0);
        
        free(arg.array);
        
        shmdt(addr);
        
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);
        
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argc` y `argv` no son variables locales. Son parámetros. Por lo tanto la función `main` debería estar definida cómo `int main(int argc, char** argv){ ... }`.

Comment: @Mateo Esa es la síntaxis K&R, antigua, anterior a ANSI: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3092006/8663418. O, lo que es lo mismo, ese código es un ejemplo de algún libro con mas de 30 años de antiguedad :-O

Comment: @Trauma no lo sé, pero gcc se queja. Si dijera el compilador que está usando podríamos saberlo.