# cómo hacer el fork en C

Tags: c, linux, git-fork

¿Cómo se hace el fork en este código?

Tengo el siguiente código en el que tengo que hacer una aplicación formada por 2 procesos dependientes con una relación padre-hijo. El proceso padre obtendrá por parámetro
el nombre de un directorio (o carpeta). A partir de dicho nombre, el proceso padre determinará si es un directorio o no. Si no existe ningún directorio con ese nombre, el proceso padre debe mostrar en pantalla un mensaje. Si existe el directorio, el proceso padre obtendrá el nombre de cada archivo y subdirectorio contenido en dicho directorio. Para cada nombre obtenido, el proceso padre lo enviará al proceso hijo para que este lo visualice por pantalla.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define KEY 100
#define EL 0        //ID del semáforo
#define ED 1        //ID del semáforo
#define MB 2        //ID del semáforo
#define N 256       //tamaño del buffer

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    
    int status;
    int semid;
    int shmid;
    int IN;
    int OUT;
    
    struct sembuf sem_oper;
    
    union semun {
        int val;
        struct semid_ds *semstat;
        unsigned short *array;
    } arg;
    
    struct buffer {
        char nombre[N];
    } buffer, *addr;
    
    DIR *dir;
    
    struct dirent *ent;
    
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("\nERROR, no se ha introducido ningún parámetro\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("\nERROR, hay parámetros de más\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    semid = semget(KEY, 3, 0770 | IPC_CREAT);
    
    if (semid == -1) {
    printf("\nERROR en la creación de semáforos\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    
    arg.array = (unsigned short *) malloc (sizeof (short)*3);
    arg.array[EL] = N;
    arg.array[ED] = 0;
    arg.array[MB] = 1;
    
    semctl (semid, 3, SETALL, arg);
    
    /* Crear a la memoria compartida (el padre lo crea) */
    shmid = shmget(KEY, sizeof(buffer)*N, 0770 | IPC_CREAT);
    
    if (shmid == -1) {
    printf("\nERROR en la creación de Memoria Compartidan\n");
    exit(1);        
    }
    
    addr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
```

Comment: ¿No es la misma [pregunta que ya hiciste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/567694/errores-de-compilaci%c3%b3n-en-lenguaje-c)? Por cierto, el código está cortado